# why is time format getting changed for 00:00:00 time in UTC 24 hour format to 24:00:00

Tags: javascript

I have the date as:

```
var date = new Date('2021-08-25T00:00:00.000+00:00');
```

I am formatting time as:

```
 time = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-Us', {
          hour12: false,
          hour: '2-digit',
          minute: '2-digit',
          second: '2-digit',
          timeZone: 'UTC',
        });
```

Why the time is getting changed to 24:00:00 instead of 00:00:00. And how can i have it as 00:00:00

Comment: Which browser are you using? It seems to be working as expected in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: @FelixKling I am checking in edge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `en-Gb` fixes it.

```js
var date = new Date('2021-08-25T00:00:00.000+00:00');

let time = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-Gb', {
          hour12: false,
          hour: '2-digit',
          minute: '2-digit',
          second: '2-digit',
          timeZone: 'UTC',
        });
        
 console.log(time);
```

Comment: How is switching locals a solution to the problem?